# Raspberry Pi apt-get upgrade failed

Tags: raspberry-pi, apt-get

When trying to get the camera for the raspberry pi working, I had to start with an update and upgrade. When doing so, I received an error which I was forced to remove the update lists and try again. That is when I got this error in return.

```
Fetched 14.0 kB in 25s (541 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 174 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,111 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 63964 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6:armhf 2.13-37+rpi1 (using .../libc6_2.13-38+rpi2_armhf.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc6:armhf ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: incorrect data check'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.13-38+rpi2_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.13-38+rpi2_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I did an install -f another update, nothing i'm doing seems to be fixing this error. Any assistance on this would be most appreciated. I don't want to just remove the the problem package to be updated, i'd like the whole thing to be updated. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

first remove local apt cache by doing "apt-get clean", and then try your "apt-get install" again.

Note however, if your archives got corrupted in the first place, your SDcard might be low quality or broken (or fake), so you might want to check that too if problems persists (running fsck, checking SDcard with [F3](https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3) or similar)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an upgrade and/or configuration has to take place for the apt-get.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```